# I am trying to decrypt my fille but only receiving 1 character

Tags: python

```
    #this will import randInt for random number generator and sleep
from random import randint
from time import sleep
    #function

def encrypt(plaintext,key):
        #naming variables
        cypherText=''
        #encryption
        for char in plaintext:
            #this if is used so if the user does a space the program will continue the encryption. Without it the program will simply encrpyt the first word before the space
            if char== ' ':
                cypherText=cypherText+char
                #if characters are all upper case the program will use the ASCII values from 97 with negative index
            elif char.isupper():
                cypherText= cypherText+ chr((ord(char)+key-65)%26+65)
                #if characters all lower case the program  will use the ASCII values from 65 with negative index
            else:
                cypherText= cypherText+ chr((ord(char)+key-97)%26+97)
        #this will return the Text out of the function
        fh=open(input("Enter File Name with .txt \n"),'w')
        fh.write(cypherText)
        fh.close()
        encryptedtext=plaintext
        return cypherText

def decrypt(plaintext,key):
        #naming variables
        decryptedtext=' '
        for char in plaintext:
            if char==' ':
                plaintext=plaintext+char
            #this will decrypt upper case characters
            elif (char.isupper()):
                decryptedText += chr((ord(char) -65 + key)% 26 + 65)
            #this will decrypt lower case characters
            else:
                decryptedText += chr((ord(char) -97 + key)% 26 + 97)

        return decryptedText

    #here the user will enter the text
    #here the program will display the menu



print("------- M A I N  M E N U -------\n A. Generate Random Key\n B. Encrypt File \n C. Decrypt File \n X. Quit")
option=''
while (option.lower()!='x'):
    option=input("Enter your choice\n A. B. C. X.\n")
    if(option.lower()=='a'):
            key=randint(1,25)
            print("---------------")
            print("The Key generated is: " ,key)
            print("---------------")

    elif (option.lower()=='b'):
            sleep(1)
            key=int(input("Please enter the Encryption Key"))
            print("The key is ",key)
            plaintext=input("Enter the text you want to encrypt \n")
            print("The encryption is sucessfully complete:",encrypt(plaintext,key))
            
    elif(option.lower()=='c'):
        key=int(input("Please enter the same key you used for the encryption"))
        with open(input('Enter file name to decrypt')) as file:
            plaintext=file.read()
            print("The file was sucessfully decrypted: ",decrypt(plaintext,key))
            
    elif(option.lower()=='x'):
        print("The program is now quitting...")
        sleep(3)
        quit()
```

**This program is supposed to be an encrpyter and decrypter. Encrypting works fine and saves to a file but for whatever reason the decryption part only shows a character. I am using the ASCII method here. I have checked indentation and everything. I'm kind of a beginner and tried everything I could to make this work
Thanks :)**

Comment: btw I suggest that in your `decrypt()` function you call the parameter: `cyphertext` and the decrypted text: `plaintext`. You have already confused the two with your current namings.

Comment: ok i will arrange that thanks. Still but the key parameter i need as it is the shift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to use `+=` for example `cypherText += cypherText+char`, because when you use `=` you are resetting the whole string.

Another this is, I've already used  a decoder so ill show you the code I've used and maybe you can change it to fit you, here it is:

```
                key += 1
                newMessage = ''
                for character in message:
                  if character in noCapAlphabet:
                    position = noCapAlphabet.find(character)
                    newPosition = (position - key) % 26
                    newCharacter = noCapAlphabet[newPosition]
                    newMessage += newCharacter
                    
                  elif character in number:
                    position = number.find(character)
                    newPosition = (position - key) % 10
                    newCharacter = number[newPosition]
                    newMessage += newCharacter
                    
                  elif character in capAlphabet:
                    position = capAlphabet.find(character)
                    newPosition = (position - key) % 26
                    newCharacter = capAlphabet[newPosition]
                    newMessage += newCharacter

                  else:
                    newMessage += character
```

`noCapAlphabet`, `number` and `capAlphabet` are arrays

---

Edit, the function can work as well:

```
message = 'ifmmp'
noCapAlphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
capAlphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
number = '0123456789'
def decrypt(message):
    key = 1
    newMessage = ''
    for character in message:
        if character in noCapAlphabet:
            position = noCapAlphabet.find(character)
            newPosition = (position - key) % 26
            newCharacter = noCapAlphabet[newPosition]
            newMessage += newCharacter
                        
        elif character in number:
            position = number.find(character)
            newPosition = (position - key) % 10
            newCharacter = number[newPosition]
            newMessage += newCharacter
                        
        elif character in capAlphabet:
            position = capAlphabet.find(character)
            newPosition = (position - key) % 26
            newCharacter = capAlphabet[newPosition]
            newMessage += newCharacter

        else:
            newMessage += character
            
    return newMessage

print(decrypt(message))
```

Comment: The decryption still shows a character. Thanks anyways tho

Comment: Is it possible to put it in a function and recall the function in the menu? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If that helped, read: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), and about [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) and [voting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up).

Comment: Alright i will have a go. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Oh please bear in mind that `noCapAlphabet`, `number` and `capAlphabet` are txt files and you might want to change it.

Comment: Yes, I will change them and suit them to my needs. Thanks :)

Comment: 1 question. This is for the decryption right?

Comment: yes, this is my code for a Ceaser cypher decrypter, so you will have to change some variables

Comment: if this helped you might want to read voting, and accepting answers, links are above

Comment: I am assuming i can use this code similarly for encryption right? meaning i can change some mathematicals and use it for encryptions

Comment: yes you can use it to encrypt but change the `(position - key)` to `(position + key)`

Comment: Ok I will have a go at it

Comment: if this post has helped, you might want to accept this as the answer

Comment: The part where you have **elif character in number** does that refer to the index so the program avoids going out of range?

Comment: No, this code is a Ceaser cypher decrypter so `number` is an array and it checks whether the encrypted string has a number in it

Comment: I will let you know if this worked or not :)

Comment: If it has then you can put this as the answer

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot make it to work as a function. I will try using it without the function and let you know

Comment: So your answer worked without the function so ill count that as a good one. Thanks ill  try make it work in my program

Comment: Ive found a way to get the function running just look at my edit

Comment: I will fit it in my program. If it works  I owe you one

Comment: I'm just helping, you don't owe me one, this site is to help people

Comment: It worked for now. Now i will try to implement file saving. But your reasoning was right. Thanks once again